# How to prevent serialization all data of related User object

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity `CreditCard` which is related to the `User` entity:

```
/**
 * CreditCard
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="credit_card")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CreditCard
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string")
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="creditCard")
     */
    protected $user;

}
```

When I serialize `CreditCard` entity, it also serializes `user` field with user data like password, etc.

```
{{ creditCard|serialize }}
```

gives:

```
{"id":70,"value":"1721742","user":{"id":1,"username":"1721742","email":"hsz@domain.tld","enabled":true,"salt":"xxx","password":"yyy","last_login":"2013-05-27T09:18:30+0200","locked":false, ..... } }
```

How can I prevent it to allow serialize only `id`, `username` of `User` entity ?

Comment: Not sure if I get your question correctly, but did you try: setIgnoredAttributes - comes with the normalizer (http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/GetSetMethodNormalizer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the [serializable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface and unset the user interface in the serialize() method.

With this interface you write your own serialize() and unserialize() methods that will be called automatically, so you can implement anything you want

Comment: Is it possible to implement with this interface a behaviur that will return only `id, username, email` if I serialize `CreditCard`, but if I serialize directly `User` entity - it will return whole dataset ?